# How to remove map animation while its being loading?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm working on an app that uses map and its functionality. Map shows animation for pin annotations. I don't want that animation within map when zooming. Is there any way to remove this animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In    `viewForAnnotation` method

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView =[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"] autorelease];


        annView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        annView.animatesDrop=False;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
    }
```

here `annView.animatesDrop=False;` will turn off drop animation

Comment: thanks chatur. It Works for pin annotations dropping. But i want to stop map animation that is performed while zooming process of map. Do you know any way to stop this map animation?

Comment: @DiptiYW, Sorry if I misunderstood the question but I cannot think of any animation that is performed on annotations while zooming. Are you talking of annotation callout(annotation box)?

Comment: while zooming on map what we can see is like zoom animation. I don't want to use that. Is their some possibility to stop this zoom animation?